# Is it possible to get a log if new products are added to Magento?

Tags: magento, import, magmi

Is it possible to get a log if new products are added to magento? I'm working on automating product import and edit existing products in Magento, but I would like to see a log which products are new after the import. Is this possible With Magento or Magmi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has a function that appends anything to a log file or creates it if it doesn't exist.

Mage::log("Product added", null, 'somefilename.log', true);

You just have to find a right place to put it in.
Read more: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/choosing-a-right-event-to-observe/